# Java - Android - inherited function or public static function

Tags: java, android, performance, inheritance, static-methods

All my activities have access to database which is a lazy singleton. All activites are derived from BaseActivity class. BaseActivity checks and initializes database if needed.

I'm thinking of putting the db initialization code block (this work can be heavy) in the BaseActivity class or making it as a public static function (in other class).

The db initialization code block initilizes not only the database but also other lazy singletons.

Does this change my app performance? Which one for a good structure?
Thanks.

Comment: If you are using the db all across try considering it declaring in Application level than activity level.

Comment: Have you consider using any DI frameworks? Then you could have regular class `DBhelper` with all heavy work, and you could inject it whenever it's needed. Cowe will be cleaner and easier to debug.

Comment: @sumandas Thanks you but application android class vs singleton pattern is a arguing topic. And I prefer a lazy singleton than a application class ;)

Comment: In ideal world every class solves one problem. It is better to keep code for database on its own class. Check out this pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: @user902383 I'm using `SQLiteOpenHelper`